# How to use positionType to pull a component up when the above component is not displayed in jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

`positionType="Float"` on a component pulls itself down if the above component stretches. But doesn't move up if the above component shrinks/not displayed.

Below is the version used:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
     <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code that will reproduce the above issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="acaa0a15-dc0f-462c-8d16-14f0b7325696">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="500" splitType="Prevent">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="19" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9547d877-993c-4bb4-becc-cf70a0cc1bc2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text11111111111111111111]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="150" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9e7dbe2e-2fed-41c8-82ce-c0c6886c8eda">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text22222222222222222222]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Above code displays only second static text component but not first. Because the `printWhenExpression` in the first is `false`.

Now I want the second component to display in place of first, but it doesn't. As a result I'm getting space there.

How I can remove that empty space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [JasperReports documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/stretch/index.html) emphasize mine

> positionType="Float" - The element floats in its parent section if it is pushed downward by other elements found above it. It tries to **conserve the distance** between it and the neighboring elements placed immediately above it.

The second reportElement will not move up to where the first reportElement is because it **conserve the distance** between them. The distance illustrated in image below:

[image: Empty space]

Your solution is remove this space!, if you like reportElement 2 to take reportElement 1 place

## Solution A

Remove the space but keep position of second reportElement if first is present. Increase height of reportElement 1.

[image: Increase height]

## Solution B

Remove the space by moving reportElement 2 up, if it is a textField (dynamic text) you can use `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` on reportElement 1 to push reportElement 2 down if reportElement 1 is overflowing.

[image: Move up]

Comment: I didn't understand solutionA. Should the y attribute of second component be dynamically set?

Comment: @User1230321 you should modify height of reportElement 1 so that it remove the empty space

Comment: All other settings are the same as in your example (position float)

Comment: There is another question on jasper reports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391553/how-to-avoid-space-in-between-when-components-are-dynamically-not-visible-in-jas Please see if you can answer.

Comment: @User1230321 ok I posted an answer, have fun