# How to avoid space in between when components are dynamically not visible in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've some 11 staticText components here. when I display only first and eight components I see a huge gap between them. I don't have any space between each component. 
My assumption is 'isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"' on a component will allow the next component to display in its place if it's not getting displayed. But that's not happening here.

Below is the jasper reports version used:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
     <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="acaa0a15-dc0f-462c-8d16-14f0b7325696">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="581" splitType="Prevent">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="19" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9547d877-993c-4bb4-becc-cf70a0cc1bc2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text11111111111111111111]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9e7dbe2e-2fed-41c8-82ce-c0c6886c8eda">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text22222222222222222]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="100" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="75d03d01-ae6f-40e3-92d4-bed93a7cf671">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text3333333333333]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="260" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d351c771-3c5f-4318-9a47-9363831908b6">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[7777777777777777777]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="140" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="cfa2937f-8ddd-4608-95e5-f3ec1d0dbea2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[4444444444444444444]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="180" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9e69343a-e1e7-4af9-90ae-d5d7c128a30a">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[55555555555555555555555]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="220" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="63d16d03-d637-406c-b128-06e8741a927f">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[66666666666666666]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="300" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="2f7e0222-a2be-47ff-be3c-3d404c40ab1c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[888888888888888888]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="340" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d87a01b5-f041-4c41-83e9-57b2e350f5b2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[999999999999999999999999]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="380" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b2017166-a731-4ebf-86f9-42a9dfe9d95a">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[1010101010101010]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="420" width="381" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="65c6b70e-7e12-4d38-b9d3-b9456e77c1e7">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is the screenshot of the gap showing:

[image]

The output is same for splitType "Prevent", "Immediate" and "Stretch". Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `splitType`, the 2 parameters to use is

1. `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"`, remove the component
2. `positionType="Float"`, float the component relative to others.

and then you need to have correct design, 0 space between components.

Your problem is the -1 space between components (the y differenze is 40 but the height is 41), switch the height to 40 in all your `staticText` elements this is the output.

[image: output]

The space you see between the remaining components are the height 40, if you like to remove this also you need to do something similar as in [cgrim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9709361/cgrim)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52394774/5292302).

Answer (score 1):

That gap is produced by additional space of each `staticText`. When you change `height="41"` on `height="16"` the gap will be minimal.

But in this case there will be no space after each visible text. If you want to have empty line after each visible text then you can use `textField` instead of `staticText` (does not support stretch with overflow) with value ending by `\n` and `isStretchWithOverflow="true"`. For example:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="300" y="0" width="381" height="16" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="2bef002c-8a26-4572-946a-d8a0e4116baa">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: This is the program I've written for reproducing the issue. My program has other components like charts and tables. Irrespective of the height, when the previous component isn't getting displayed, I want the current component to get displayed in its position.

Comment: This answer is correct but what OP is missing is that the height=41 gives a -1 space between components that actually confused jasper report export engine, hence it can't float components correctly, I have posted an answer since OP pinged me on another question and taken the liberty to reference this answer if the remaining additional space needs to be removed.