JasperReports - Avoid optional textField taking space horizonatally between two textFields
There are 3 textFields arranged horizontally side by side. The middle one is optional if lenght is less than 1, and I don't want it to occupy the space and get third textFields appear on its place. All three textFields are of different widhts. But middle always takes space between the first one and last one.
I refferred this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406805/552423
<title>
        <band height="277" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="80" y="150" width="100" height="30" uuid="4d45e20b-8a5c-457b-8c99-7b3ca64d8325"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field 1"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="180" y="150" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="5a93c08e-f110-414c-8c1a-58970d1a9a7c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{optionalText}.length() !=0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{optionalText}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="280" y="150" width="100" height="30" uuid="51d2153f-02c4-4a4d-b69f-ca0ef632e65a"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field 2"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
</title>


